# What should callback functions default value be in object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, extend

### The Issue

I am trying to specify options for an objects method and one of the options is a callback function. I am using the jQuery `extend` method to apply my default values to the options parameter but am unsure what value I should set for the callback parameter.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var options = $.extend({
    wrapper:    '#wrapper', // Define the default wrapper to prepend to
    fade:       true, // Fade the overlay by default
    callback:   function(){} // Define the callback function
},options);
```

### Question

Is the above the best method for assigning a default value to the callback? Or would it be better to set it to false? I thought if you tried to call `options.callback()` and the callback is set to false then you would receive an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a non function default requires the explicit check before invocation.

Having an empty function requires the overhead of invoking it *(though minimal)*.

There's no right way. It's totally up to you. If you do use an empty function, you can use [`$.noop`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop/) to reuse an existing one.

```
var options = $.extend({
    wrapper:    '#wrapper', // Define the default wrapper to prepend to
    fade:       true, // Fade the overlay by default
    callback:   $.noop // Define the callback function
},options);
```

Comment: I know this is a very stupid question but believe it or not I have never used a callback like this. Are the brackets after `noop` necessary? So does it matter that it is not `noop()`?

Comment: @BenCarey: No, you shouldn't include the brackets. The `()` is the function call operator. When placed after a function, it calls that function. What we want here is to merely *assign* the function to the `callback:` property. :)

Comment: Just thought about that last comment about the brackets and very much regret writing it!! haha, not my finest moment :-)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a built in function that does nothing called [$.noop](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/).